# Does code running in a WebWorker run in a different realm?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Does code running in a WebWorker run in a different JavaScript runtime realm?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does.

[Step 6 in the WHATWG spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html).

> Call the JavaScript InitializeHostDefinedRealm() abstract operation
>   with the following customizations:

Comment: Since there is always a global environment associated with a realm, this would have been my guess. Otherwise webworkers and page code would have to share the same global environment which we know is not the case.

Comment: Ben, if this is of interest you might also want to look at agents and agent clusters (recently added to the JavaScript and HTML Standards). Those underpin concurrency and help quantify how a worker is different from a realm created by an `iframe` element, for instance.