# Is it safe to modify a Map concurrently?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Map that keeps a status of a bunch of checks. Each check will only modify one key using `.set` will there be any issues if two concurrent checks try to modify the map at the same time?

I have setInterval doing some check in the background and setting the status of the check in a map. In other languages I would have a problem if two things tried to edit the map at the same time. Not actual code but I'm wondering if the following would be safe to do.

```
var myMap = new Map();

var a = setInterval(someCheckA, 1000);
var b = setInterval(someCheckB, 1000);


function someCheckA() {
    myMap.set('A', 'status is good');
}

function someCheckB() {
    myMap.set('B', 'status is good');
}

// do stuff with myMap
```

Comment: Can you elaborate, give some example code? It's not entirely clear what the question is asking. Keep in mind that Javascript is single-threaded

Comment: @CertainPerformance updated

Comment: Javascript is single threaded. There are no concurrency issues.

Comment: JS is not single-threaded if you're using web-workers or service-workers

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no issue with two functions doing `myMap.set` at "the same time" - and that's because they aren't doing it at the same time. JavaScript is single-threaded; while the functions in the two `setInterval`s will both activate once every second, they do so in turn, not simultaneously. Therefore, there's no issue.

Comment: PWAs change that game, since they use web-workers under the hood, and those are actually other threads.

Comment: @JoeyBaruch That's true in general, but web workers [each operate under their own Realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012104/does-code-running-in-a-webworker-run-in-a-different-realm), which means they can't share variables or objects (such as Maps—it's possible to send strings and JSON-serializable objects, but that's not the same as working with the same actual object, just a local copy recreated from a string). There's still no risk of concurrency issues (which you might encounter in other languages) as the two execution contexts aren't accessing the same areas in memory.